# ASP.NET Core 2.0: How to update extend properties of IDentityUser?

Tags: asp.net-identity

It is a project created with ASP.NET Core Web Application MVC Template. Personal is selected for Authentication.

I extend IDentityUser to add properties like Title, Institution, FirstName LastName. I am able to register new user with these extend properties. However I also want user be able to update these properties after log in.

The original property of IDentityUser, like PhoneNumber is updated with  scaffolded code below.

```
var phoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
if (model.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
{
    var setPhoneResult = await _userManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, model.PhoneNumber);
    if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Unexpected error occurred setting phone number for user with ID '{user.Id}'.");
    }
}
```

It seems I also need extend UserManager to create functions like

```
setTitleAsync(TUser user, string title);
setInstitutionAsync(TUser user, string instituion);
setFirstNameAsync(TUser user, string firstName);
setLastNameAsync(TUser user, string lastName);
```

I checked the source code of NET Core 1.0, the implementation of  SetPhoneNumberAsync is like this:

```
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var store = GetPhoneNumberStore();
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
    }
    await store.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, phoneNumber, CancellationToken);
    await store.SetPhoneNumberConfirmedAsync(user, false, CancellationToken);
    await UpdateSecurityStampInternal(user);
    return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
```

I think this is too complicated for such a common request. Besides, I also don't know what the xxxStore works for.

Anyone has experience to deal with this? Thanks a lot.

Another way to update these properties is update them by access the DB directly. But that would not be consistent with existed code.